# Need a Case Sensitive Exists on an attribute to find duplicates

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have XML such as:

```
<History>
   <Event></Event>
   <Event></Event>
</History>
```

And I need to add a sort order attribute to each event to get this:

```
<History>
   <Event SortOrder="1"></Event>
   <Event SortOrder="2"></Event>
</History>
```

Somehow I have ended up with a few rows having sort order twice, one upper case and one lower case. (and the values are different).

I am not sure how this happened.  I have a stored procedure to add the sort order to existing records, and we have dotNet code someone else wrote to add the sort order to new records.

How can I find the element with the duplicate attributes?
I try this but I don't think the exists is case sensitive.

```
select m.c.query('.') theElement
       from Histories h
              cross apply h.XMLHistory.nodes('History/Entry') m(c)
       where (
            XmlHistory.exist('(History/Entry[(@SortOrder)])')= 1       
            and XmlHistory.exist('(History/Entry[(@sortOrder)])')= 1 
        )
```

My proc to add the sort order does this:

```
update Histories
   set 
   XmlHistory.modify('
      insert attribute SortOrder {sql:variable("@sortOrder")}
         into (History/Entry[not(@SortOrder)])[1]
      ')
where HistoryID=@historyID
```

This is adding SortOrder when it's not there.  Could it be the lowercase version is already there and then I add the uppercase version?  I don't think so because my select above do not seem to be case sensitive?

1. How can I find the dups?  I think I need a case sensitive exists.
2. Does it look like my update causes the dups?

Comment: If you're using XQUERY `sortorder` would not return values for `SortOrder`, it's already case sensitive.

Comment: Take this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dff124c1a489575814f0860097f9834a). Notice that each row only returns 1 value, not 2.

Comment: I think value is cases sensitive but not exists.  Take a look at this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7757a1cc416ab412f3e25d4a813a6b72 .  I added a where exists to only give the lowercase one, but I got both.

Comment: That's actually `exist` not `EXISTS`. `EXISTS` is a T-SQL Keyword. You could, therefore, use `WHERE YE.E.value('@sortorder','int') IS NOT NULL` (based on my db fiddle) to find rows that have a value for `sortorder`.

Answer (score 0):

`exist()` is case sensitive.

This will return the elements that has both a `SortOrder`attribute and a `sortOrder` attribute.

```sql
select m.c.query('.') as theElement
from Histories as h
  cross apply h.XMLHistory.nodes('/History/Event') as m(c)
where m.c.exist('@SortOrder') = 1 and
      m.c.exist('@sortOrder') = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath is case sensitive like XML. If you want to select every `Entry` having 
 an attribute with name `SortOrder` in any letter case combination use:

```
History/Entry[@*[translate(name(),'SORTDE','sortde') = 'sortorder']]
```